# Authenticate connection to remote repository before committing files

Tags: svn, shell-script, bash-scripting

All,
I have an app (using shell script) that automates the process of committing to svn , generating svn info and emailing it. But every now and then I get the following

> Authentication realm: < svn://host.example.com:3690> example realm
>   Username:  testuser
>   Password for 'testuser':

This usually happens when user changes the password( this is a system wide password) used for connecting to the Remote Repository. My app gets stuck at this stage since it doesn't check if the password changed before adding and committing.I just want my app to authenticate the user credentials before commit process and alert the user that authentication has failed and he needs to provide the new password. Is it possible to do this using shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the --non-interactive option when committing a file, it will not request for authentication when the commit operation fails. This is useful if you're running Subversion inside an automated script and it's more appropriate to have Subversion fail than to prompt for more information.